# How I do make this fake logo and nav links line up better?

Tags: nav

I'm on day three of learning web development and I'm struggling with getting things where I want them. I want my little logo (slothw.png) to lign up better with my nav links. I want it to line up in the exact same way that the logo of a website lines up with the name you give it on the bookmark bar in Chrome. I hope that makes sense and thanks for the help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jydI2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s a job for css :).

You case use the flex display mode and them set the align-items property to center.

```
 .myClassWithCenteredChildren { display: flex; align-items: center; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked instantly! Apologies though as I don't think my 3 pictures uploaded with my question, which showed my HTML page, CSS page and a screenshot of my actual webpage. Those probably would have helped too lol